# Meaning of a function being "defined" on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions, terminology

I have a somewhat basic question: What does it mean when someone says that a function, say, $f$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$? Does it means that the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$, or that the range of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$, or both?

Comment: It means that the domain is $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the domain is $\Bbb R$.  The range can be anything.

Comment: Turning the comment into an answer.  CW.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1489046)

Comment: @Anonymous:  I believe it directly answers the question and does so correctly.  It was a comment which several people upvoted.  When we say a function is defined on a set, it means that set is the domain of the function.

Comment: @RossMilikan - I agree with you. This directly answers the OP’s question. However, I have a quick follow up question myself: when we say a function is defined on a set, we mean that set is the domain of the function (as you said) - but does this also mean the codomain can be anything, in general (unless specified)?

Comment: @TaylorRendon:  yes.  I could define a function on $\Bbb R$ that takes all numbers that have an odd integer part to blue and numbers that have an even integer part to red.  That is a fine function on $\Bbb R$